# How to dispay input values in real time in middle of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display input value in replacement for a word in the middle of text in real time using like this:
How are you doing Mr. [name]
is your country [country]?

I tried to use keyup and replace the [name] with input value but this do it only once and not updating cos the [name] not exits anymore to replace the input value with.

```
        $(".mailer-form input[name=person-name]").keyup(function(){
             var name = $('input[name=person-name]').val();
          var country = $('input[name=person-country]').val();
          var text = $('.email-content').text().replace('[name]', name);
         $('.email-content').text(text);
```

Comment: For the purposes of creating practical examples and answers, it helps if we have the relevant HTML as well. That way we can see what you're working with and provide a functional demonstration of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the original text, then use it as template.

```
const template = {
     ".email-content": $('.email-content').text()
};

$(".mailer-form input[name=person-name]").keyup(function(){

     const name = $(this).val();
     const country = $('input[name=person-country]').val();
     const text = template['.email-content'].replace('[name]', name);

     $('.email-content').text(text);
});
```

Comment: it works very fine... thank you so much. but I think you should do some explanation to you code as the rule of this website...